# Save pyspark dataframe as RecordIO protobuf

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I want to save my pyspark dataframe in RecordIO protobuf format. I am using **Amazon EMR** to run my pyspark scripts, and I want to use **AWS SageMaker** to train a machine learning model.
SageMaker pipe mode only accept *RecordIO protobuf* as input, hence my question

I have tried to save my *pyspark* dataframe as recordio protobuf as the following:

```
output_path = f"s3://my_path/output_processed"
df_transformed.write.format("sagemaker").mode("overwrite").save(output_path)
```

But when I run the sagemaker model I get an error of missing values even though my dataframe does not have missing values. What might be the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: First I would suggest to create a small dataset with say 20 rows where you are definitely sure that there are no missing values through manual inspection over the data. Then be able to train the model without any errors. If this passes then it implies you indeed have no issue with dataformat or your training pipeline. This also points that your larger original dataset has problems so you might need to do some analysis.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, I am working with a small chunk of data. Is the line of code I provided correct for saving pyspark dataframe as recordio protobuf? @user238607

Comment: Can you provide some stack trace for the error? Also, I am assuming when you are saying there are no missing values that include check for both `None` and `empty string`